# Adjective position in a string resource

Tags: android, android-resources

In French the position of the adjective can be before or after the noun. Depending of the length of the adjective, changing the position of the adjective can be mandatory to make a correct sentence. For example :

> **Bonne** qualité nutritionnelle pour ce repas
>
> Qualité nutritionnelle **médiocre** pour ce repas

I know plurals are implemented in Android, and also gender agreement with the SelectFormat class, but nothing on changing word order, e.g. adjective position, in a string resource.

Comment: Possibly not viable solution: Make the whole sentence a resource for each option

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MessageFormat` with a custom pattern. For that example:

```
String pattern = "{1, select, before {{0} qualité nutritionnelle} other {Qualité nutritionnelle {0}}} pour ce repas";
MessageFormat msgFmt = new MessageFormat(pattern, new ULocale("fr"));

Object args[] = {"Bonne", "before"};
Log.d("MessageFormatTAG",msgFmt.format(args));

Object args2[] = {"médiocre", "after"};
Log.d("MessageFormatTAG",msgFmt.format(args2))
```

Comment: The piece of code you gave me looks right but I have this exception : ``java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unknown format type: select``
Same thing when executing the code example in SelectFormat android doc